# What is this "[0 ... 255] =" syntax in C?

Tags: c, gcc-extensions

Refering to [js0n.c](https://github.com/quartzjer/js0n)

The code syntax is as below:

```
    static void *gostruct[] =
    {
        [0 ... 255] = &&l_bad,
        ['\t'] = &&l_loop, [' '] = &&l_loop, ['\r'] = &&l_loop, ['\n'] = &&l_loop,
        ['"'] = &&l_qup,
        [':'] = &&l_loop, [','] = &&l_loop,
        ['['] = &&l_up, [']'] = &&l_down, // tracking [] and {} individually would allow fuller validation but is really messy
        ['{'] = &&l_up, ['}'] = &&l_down,
        ['-'] = &&l_bare, [48 ... 57] = &&l_bare, // 0-9
        [65 ... 90] = &&l_bare, // A-Z
        [97 ... 122] = &&l_bare // a-z
    };

........
.......

l_bad:
    *vlen = cur - json; // where error'd
    return 0;

........
........
```

Can anyone explain what is being done here? What does syntax `[0 ... 255]` and 
`&&l_bad` do here?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`...` is an extension provided by GCC

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ...
>   last] = value`. This is a GNU extension. For example,
>
> ```
>  int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

`&&` is another extension

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values

> You can get the address of a label defined in the current function (or
>   a containing function) with the unary operator `&&`. The value has
>   type `void *`. This value is a constant and can be used wherever a
>   constant of that type is valid. For example:
>
> ```
>  void *ptr;
>  /* ... */
>  ptr = &&foo;
> ```

Comment: putting it all together that code is making a jump table that uses ascii values for indices, presumably for a parser.

Comment: Specifically a JSON parser, so far as I can tell.

Comment: So, since labels and variables have separate namespaces, how does the parser distinguish `&&foo` meaning "address of the label `foo`" from `&&foo` meaning "address of the address of the variable `foo`"?   (Taking the address of an address produces, I believe, undefined behavior, but it _is_ syntactically valid.)

Comment: The address-of operator (&) cannot be applied to an rvalue, which is what is returned by the address-of operator.

Comment: In GCC, you get an error along the lines of "label expected: i" since it assumes unary && is address-of-label. In MSVC, it rightly assumes unary && is a syntax error. If you do `&(&i)` in either, you get an error along the lines of "expected: l-value"

Comment: @KevinM that makes sense.  When did it become a syntax error to apply the address-of operator (&) to an rvalue?  I'm guessing in C99, perhaps?  The last time I used Visual C++ regularly was around 1998, which would have been the pre-C99 ANSI standard, and the compiler allowed it then (I know because I remember a typo of a doubled-up `&` getting into production code!).

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller `&&` is an entirely separate token from `&`, so there's no way the standard C grammar could interpret `&&x` as "address of address of x" regardless of the value category of `&x`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes You're confusing the standard with the implementation thereof.  How do you know how the lexing and parsing stages worked in Microsoft's C compiler circa 1998?  (I'll save you the trouble: You can't, unless you worked at MS then.)  Your answer is analogous to saying that prefix `--` and unary `-` are two different tokens, so there's no need for the parser to disambiguate them--clearly a circular argument.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller You asked whether this changed in C99.  I just wanted to indicate that it did not; `&&x` has never parsed that way by any version of the standard.  (Of course, MSVC can and does do whatever it wants.)

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller: `--` is always parsed as `--`, and `&&` is always parsed as `&&`. C99 §6.4¶4: _the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token_

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller -- MSVC likely was treating && as a unary "address-of-address-of-x" operator (weird, but unsurprising)

Comment: This code would be utterly broken using a C++11 compiler : "..." and "&&" are now valid and official operators, but in completely different context.